# Unable to drop foreign key in SQL server

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-server-express, drop

I am trying this query to drop a foreign key `ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_User_UserTypeID`.

But I am getting this

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

Answer (score 0):

SQL FOREIGN KEY on CREATE TABLE : -

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

SQL FOREIGN KEY on ALTER TABLE :-

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

DROP a FOREIGN KEY Constraint :-

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder;
```

**NOTE**
Should not have any dependency on foreign key while dropping key constraints, otherwise you will not be able to drop the constraint.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_User_UserTypeID` gives me `Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'FK_User_UserTypeID' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.`